# MSDN C# Arrays tutorial

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm learning C# array syntax from the [MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). It has this code:

```
// Array-of-arrays (jagged array)
byte[][] scores = new byte[5][];

// Create the jagged array
for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
{
    scores[i] = new byte[i + 3];
}

// Print length of each row
for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Length of row {0} is {1}", i, scores[i].Length);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And says the output is:

```
Length of row 0 is 3
Length of row 1 is 4
Length of row 2 is 5
Length of row 3 is 6
Length of row 4 is 7
```

I have copy pasted the code into the main method of a console application and my console output is:

```
Length of row 0 is 3
```

Anyone know why my output is different?

Comment: Press Enter for following lines

Comment: Thanks all, lots of answers all correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program is asking you to hit Enter between successive lines of output:

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You have a `Console.ReadLine()` in there, so you have to hit enter before it shows the next line of output.
2. The Visual Studio (if you are using it) debugger is your friend (or a debugger in general).

Answer (score 2):

```
        byte[][] scores = new byte[5][];

        // Create the jagged array
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
        {
            scores[i] = new byte[i + 3];
        }

        // Print length of each row
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Length of row {0} is {1}", i, scores[i].Length);
            Console.ReadLine(); <------ Press enter here to continue, If you want your output like MSDN's, remove this line and the program will output all results
        }
```